# Renaming Columns after concatenating two Series with same Column names

Tags: pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I have two series namely x and y.

x:

| Index | Timestamp |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 2022-11-16 13:00:00 |
| 1 | 2022-11-17 13:48:00 |

y:

| Index | Timestamp |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 2022-11-16 19:13:00 |
| 1 | 2022-11-17 16:21:00 |

I combine these two series into a data frame as follows.

```
z = pd.concat([x, y], axis=1)
```

But in the dataframe both the column names appear as "Timestamp". I want to rename it.
When I used the below code it changes both column names at the same time.

```
mapping = {z.columns[0]: 'Start' }
su = z.rename(columns=mapping)
```

Preferred output:

| start | End |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-11-16 13:00:00 | 2022-11-16 19:13:00 |
| 2022-11-17 13:48:00 | 2022-11-17 16:21:00 |

How can I do this in pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Example**

```
x = pd.Series({0: '2022-11-16 13:00:00', 1: '2022-11-17 13:48:00'}, name='Timestamp')
y = pd.Series({0: '2022-11-16 19:13:00', 1: '2022-11-17 16:21:00'}, name='Timestamp')
```

**Code**

```
pd.concat([x, y], keys=['start', 'end'], axis=1)
```

result:

```
    start               end
0   2022-11-16 13:00:00 2022-11-16 19:13:00
1   2022-11-17 13:48:00 2022-11-17 16:21:00
```